# Are low ESR SMD capacitors with jumper wires between their legs and the circuit OK?

Tags: capacitor, wire, inductance, jumper, parasitic-capacitance

I have a board with two **super low ESR SMD electrolytic capacitors** which came off the switching power supply of a notebook motherboard. The legs of the capacitor are still soldered on the board. One of them has a capacitance of **47uF**, the other of  **560uF**.

With both, I have managed to create two sort of legs by soldering two wires in place of the original legs.

In order to restore the capacitors onto the board I need the jumper wires to be a bit longer than the original legs (some 2-3cm each).

My question is:
**would this extra length in the connection cause trouble in the circuit? Would the parasitic inductance / capacitance generated be low enough that I get away with this fix *in both cases*?**

Please find below the relevant pictures:
[image: Section of the board with capacitor fallen off]

[image: Capacitor with missing legs fixed with jumper wires]
Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Could you include a photo of the situation?

Comment: @uint128_t Ok, give me a few minutes.

Comment: It's impossible to say whether it will cause a problem without knowing what the circuit's doing and how sensitive it will be to a small amount of additional inductance.

Comment: @uint128_t I have added pictures of the situation.

Comment: @WillDean How should I investigate this further?

Comment: Without more data, I don't think this qualifies as an 'answer,' but the increased lead length will increase ESR at high frequencies. However, since the smaller kf ths 2 caps is a whopping 47uF, I think we're looking at energy storage or 50/60hz 'mains hum' bypassing capacitors, in which case the additional 2-3cm length should have a negligible added esr.

Comment: I don't get why you are not putting in a cap that was intended to be there

Comment: Given that the pads appear to still be there, why not simply buy the original caps and replace them?

Comment: I'm confused. 1.  you identify both boards as "the board" 2. Is the picture of the board the one the caps came from or the one the caps are going into? 3. If it's the one the caps came from, why is that at all relevant, and if it's the one the caps are going into why do you need one inch leads on the cap(s)?

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB How about the 560uF? Would it that case the jumper wires be a problem?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I am trying to put the caps where they originally were. The problem is that before I can do that I need to have legs on the caps...

Comment: @uint128_t It's would save me the hassle of ordering them and then waiting for them to arrive...

Comment: @EMFields 1. The is just one board. In one case I refer to it as "the board", in another as "the motherboard", but it's the same pcb. 2. The caps came off the same board I am trying to put them back on. 3. why do you need one inch leads on the cap(s)? Because since the legs on the capacitors are just some wires I soldered, it would be very trick soldering the them back on the board if they were very short as the heat necessary to solder on the pads would melt the solder joints keeping the legs attached to the cap.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB Would trying hurt? I mean, it solder the caps back on the board and does happens what you say, could the circuit board be damaged?

Comment: @geraldCelente the 560uF is almost guaranteed to be an "energy storage" cap, thus operating at near DC (560uF/0.56mF is actually a huge cap for anything short of a supercap) potential, so it shoud be affected about 12 times _less_ than the 47uF one. **Would trying hurt?** Most likely it won't, cause any 'permanent damage.' Assuming that they're most likely power-supply reserve capacity/fitering capacitors, the worst 'likely case' scenario is that a bit of noise wil "sneak past" and cause errant performance of the lappy (unlikely), in which case you can shorten the leads, then try again. ;-)

Comment: (P.S.) The one **danger** I do however see, is that your caps may have already become damaged & could catastrophically fail due to pre-existing damage now. In which case, they may either A: fail entirely to do their job, and allow huge transients onto the rest of your ciruit, or B: Short/arc & potentially fry your power supply (or whole motherboard) by providing a "DC short" from Vcc to GND through the failed capacitor.

Comment: When you said "came off" I took that to mean that you had removed them for some reason.  If they came off of their own volition,  throw them away, order the proper replacements, clean up that mess on the board and solder in the new caps.  @Asmyldof is  spot on on this one.

Comment: @geraldCelente: all caps i buy have legs, I am still not getting it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will wire unequivocally add too much ESR or inductance to the whole? No.

In many situations, such as bodge-testing a beta design with more capacitance, a tiny bit of wire of the appropriate diameter will only add several or tens of miliOhm to the total resistance and usually inductance is limited.

However, should you use this solution of yours? No again.

Or to put it in terms of an answer to one of your latest comments:
Actually ordering the original replacements and waiting for them, on the other hand, will save you the *potential* hassle of buying a new laptop.

Why?

A capacitor of which the legs break is not to be trusted. Those legs are spot welded (or whatever they use as a process the last few years) onto the alu-foil, so the torsion is likely to misalign aluminium foil or even short it or warp the stack-up, before the leg breaks.

This can have detrimental effects to any one of the specifications, if not all of them. A 5% to 10% error in most specifications should be allowed in the design, if the designer understands his actual job. An error of 10% in all of the specs, or a 40% error in one, on the other hand, is a whole different story.

Look at it like this: If you order the caps, put them in without destroying anything else and then it works again, you spent 3 days waiting and a buck or three. If you do it like this you have *a chance* of being out an entire laptop in trade for 3 days quicker. In which case those 3 days won't have made a damn of a difference on the following decades of no laptop.